# How to comment in and out php code inside a file

Tags: php

Using `PHP` how to comment in all `php code` inside certain `php file`

for example if i've the followig file

```
$file = 'myfile.php';
```

has only PHP code

```
<?php
$c = 'anything';
echo $c;
?>
```

I want using PHP to comment in (add `/*` just after open tag `<?php` and `*/` just before close tag `?>`) to be

```
<?php
/*
$c = 'anything';
echo $c;
*/
?>
```

And also how to do the reverse bycomment out (remove `/*   */`) to return back to

```
<?php
$c = 'anything';
echo $c;
?>
```

I've been thinking to use `array_splice` then doing `str_replace` then using `implode` and `file_put_contents` but still unable to figure out how to do this.

**Update**

Okay meanwhile getting some help over here, i was thinking about it and it comes to my mind this idea .... USING ARRAY!

to add block comment `/*` just after open tag `<?php` i will convert the content of that file into array

`$contents = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

and then i can `array push` new element at position `2` with `/*`

and to do the reverse i will use `unset($contents[1]);` to unset element at postion `2` which means, `/*` will be gone

later on i can `file_put_contents($file, $contents);` to re-write the file again.

Comment: I’d question why you need to do this regularly enough programmatically to look for a solution like this…?

Comment: @deceze the bottom line for doing this is to disable the code of a file that runs on `CronJob` command every day so i want to keep the `CronJob` command but make sure the file is effect-less (won't print anything) so i would design something like button where i can disable (by commenting) or enable (by removing the commenting) of the code inside that file .. so i'm not gonna have to login to my hosting panel and remove/add the `cronjob` command everytime i want to stop this file doing its job.

Comment: You should rather do that by moving cron config files in and out of the active configuration folder, most elegantly done by symlinking/unlinking those files. Or you set a flag somewhere and have an `if` inside the code that exits if that flag is set.

Comment: I was thinking to add status like (active/inactive) and save the status in database table so the file can check first and if active, it would runs, but in fact i do not have any privileges on database or hosting panel ... so i'm forced to follow this weird solutions.

Comment: Can you write files to the file system anywhere? Then set a small file which just contains “yes” or “no” or whatever, or just the presence of absence of the file itself is the flag, and use that instead of a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know why you want comment or uncomment the php code but I don't think it's a good way to do. **I advice you to use variable or constant, like this :**

One other way to enable or disable you code, is to use constant variable after the second time :

## TOGGLE/UNTOGGLE COMMENT :

You will be able to do :

```
uncomment("code.php", "MYENV_DEBUG"); // uncomment
uncomment("code.php", "MYENV_DEBUG"); // comment
uncomment("code.php", "MYENV_DEBUG"); // uncomment
uncomment("code.php", "MYENV_DEBUG"); // comment
```

## FIRST TIME :

[image]

## SECOND TIME :

[image]

## THIRD TIME :

[image]

## Code :

```
<?php
    function uncomment_header($name, $value) {
        return '<?php define("' . $name . '", ' . $value . '); ?>';
    }

    function uncomment($file_path, $name) {
        $current = file_get_contents($file_path);
        $regex = '/<\\?php define\\("' . $name . '", (0|1)\\); \\?>/';

        if (preg_match($regex, $current, $match)) {
            $value = ($match[1] == 1) ? 0 : 1;
            $current = preg_replace($regex, uncomment_header($name, $value), $current);
        } else {
            $header = uncomment_header($name, 1) . "\n";
            $start = 'if (' . $name . '):';
            $end = 'endif;';

            $current = $header . $current;
            $current = preg_replace('/\\/\\*(.+?)\\*\\//s', $start . '$1' . $end, $current);
        }

        file_put_contents($file_path, $current);

        return $current;
    }

    echo "<plaintext>" . uncomment("code.php", "MYENV_DEBUG");
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PREG_REPLACE :

```
<?php
    function uncomment($file_path) {
        $current = file_get_contents($file_path);
        $current = preg_replace('/\\/\\*(.+?)\\*\\//s', '$1', $current);
        file_put_contents($file_path, $current);

        return $current;
    }

    echo "<plaintext>" . uncomment("code.php");
?>
```

## BEFORE :

[image]

## AFTER :

[image]

Comment: works perfect and was very helpful to me! thanks a lot .. The bottom line for doing this is to disable the code of a file that runs on `CronJob` command every day so i want to keep the  `CronJob` command but make sure the file is effect-less (won't print anything) so i would design something like button where i can disable (by commenting) or enable (by removing the commenting) of that file .. looks pathetic world ^_^

Comment: @RehamFahmy Also you can do : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54966805/2226755 ;) To repeat this code several time.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#canned test data, a string and the file contents are the same
$contents = <<<'CODE'
<?php
$c = 'anything';
echo $c;
?>
CODE;

$contents = preg_replace(['/<\?php\s/','/\?\>/'], ['<?php/*', '*/?>'], $contents);

echo $contents;
```

Output

```
<?php/*
$c = 'anything';
echo $c;
*/?>
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5774969394e76539c3bcfe2751bd3a70523f6b1f)

NOTE - this will only work if the ending tag is present. In PHP the ending tag is actually optional.  This will also not work on things like short tags `<?` or `<?=` although it will catch the ending tags.

Because of these edge cases it's very hard to do with regex (or any string replacement).

Valid examples of PHP code

```
<?php
  $c = 'anything';
  echo $c;
?>
//-------- no ending tag ---------
<?php
  $c = 'anything';
  echo $c;
//------- short tags ---------
<? echo 'foo'; ?>

//------- short echo tags ---------
<?= $foo; ?>
  etc...
```

Good luck if you want to try to catch them all....

Comment: Shouldn't this be `/*` instead of `\*` though?

Comment: Yes, I blame my dyslexia on that.  Yes it's that bad the only reason I know my right from left is I have a scar on my right thumb lol

Comment: Sometimes I forget that I am not left handed, and I wonder why am I doing this with my left hand etc...  It's irritating.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry to hear that. I know a couple dyslexic people (and my mom is a speech therapist so I've learned a bit about it) but your "version" seems legitimately more annoying. Hope there are ways to make things better with time and exercices. Coding must be a pretty solid way to practice at least I suppose (since it genrally doesn't let you make any "basic" mistakes such as mixed up characters and the likes).

Comment: But there is little or no spell checkers for code ... lol ... so I always have issues with that.  It's less bad typing then hand writing though...  I been coding almost 9 years at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of comments in PHP 1)single line comment 2)Multiple line comment for single comment in php we just type // or # all text to the right will be ignored by PHP interpreter. for example

```
<?php
echo "code in PHP!"; // This will print out Hello World!
```

`?>` 
Result: code in PHP!

For multiple line comments multiple line PHP comment begins with " /* " and ends with " / " for example

```
<?php
/* This Echo statement will print out my message to the
the place in which I reside on.  In other words, the World. */
echo "Hello World!"; 
/* echo "My name is Noman Ali!";
echo "PHP Programmer!";
*/?>
```

Result: Hello World!

Comment: Well! thank you for sharing but in fact i did not asked about how to write a comment inside php file, my question was about how to use `php` itself to comment out the code inside another file.